# FriendSystem in Asp.net core using IdentityUser and EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I would like to create a table which contains two foreign keys. Both pointing to a userId in the AspNetUsers table. I don't know how to reference the AspNetUsers' Id Column since I didn't create a model for that myself.

It should look something like this:

```
UserId | FriendId
-----------------
ada656 | abes7e
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create folder called claim and add new class called `ApplicationUser`, this class will inherit from IdentityUser class as showing below:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`;

```
namespace YourApplication.Claims
{
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can put any column that you need to apply inside it like this:

```
namespace YourApplication.Claims
    {
        public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
        {
           public int FriendId { get; set; }
           public string FullName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

After you applied this, goto controller and initialize user manager:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

Then assign the constructor to pass the data like this:

```
public ClassName(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Then you can read the users data like this:

```
_userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
```

or read specific user data like this:

```
_userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
```

or you can delete the user like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
_userManager.DeleteAsync(user)
```

Hope this help you solve the problem.

Comment: You can add the column that you entered `FriendsId` in the AspNetUsers table in database or you can do migration if you applied the migration.